Representations on inner product spaces
Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{F}$-inner product space and $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ a linear representation that preserves the inner product. If $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$, then we say $V$ is a unitary representation, if $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$, then we say $V$ is an orthogonal representation. Now, what should I call $V$ when $\mathbb{F}$ is any arbitrary field? Do we have something like isometrical representation?

What is an inner product for an arbitrary field? Do you just mean a nondegenerate bilinear form?

There is no such word in general, because your inner form involves the axiom of positive definitness. But on arbitrary fields you have no total ordering and no positivness.
You can probably think about such expressions, but then you have to redefine your inner product (for example bilinear, symmetric, non degenerate).
I think the only reason why there are this special words "unitary" and "orthogonal" is because this two Fields (and the corresponding vector spaces) play such an important role not only in math but also in science as well. Probably the definition of an inner form has also been developed because of the important role of this two fields and the corresponding analysis behind it.
Remember: inner products induce norms and angles and they play an important role in geometry and analysis, hence are especially important/useful for real and complex analysis.
